# I'm getting following error in Jest ReferenceError: Response is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

First I had a typescript issue that my mocked data doesn't match to Response type. Then I tried to create mock data with Response constructor and got that error.

I have the following code

```
const HttpRequest = async function (
    url: string,
    options: RequestInit,
): Promise<Response> {
    try {
        return await fetch(url, options);
    } catch (error) {
        return null;
    }
};

export default HttpRequest;
```

And following test:

```
const res = new Response();
window.fetch = jest.fn(
    () => new Promise((resolve) => {
        return resolve(res);
    })
);

describe('HttpService', () => {
    it('fetchWithFeedback', async () => {
        const data = await HttpRequest('/api', { method: 'GET' });
        expect(data).toEqual(res);
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot to leave your error in the question?

Comment: No, the error that I get is ReferenceError: Response is not defined

Comment: Which env are you testing against? Is `Response` a global object available?

Comment: I'm testing browser environment. It should be available on window object.

Comment: "Response" is not available in jest electron browser so you have to mock it then

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  const changeField = (field, id, value) => {
    const newPropertyData = { ...propertyData };
    if (newPropertyData.id === id) {
      newPropertyData.field = value;
    }
  };
```

to

```
  const changeField = (field, id, value) => {
    if (propertyData.id === id) {
      setPropertyData({ ...propertyData, [field]: value })
    }
  };
```

You're not updating your state in your onChange, so it's never able to update the value, which is still "".